# How to use sqlite with Borland C++ Builder

Tags: sqlite, c++builder

I have sqlite3.dll but I'm assuming it's far more complex than simply including that file in a project and then using its functions.  Even if it was I have literally no experience using pre-built DLLs with C++ Builder applications.

So my question is,  How would I go about using sqlite in a Borland c++ builder application?  As simple an explanation or step-by-step guide as possible is preferable as my ability to do anything beyond creating apps with C++ Builder is severely limited.

Failing that,  is anyone aware of a web article that answers the same question?  I'm aware that sqlite3 has its own documentation section but I found it hard to follow and some vital links are broken.

Failing *that*...  Is there a better way to create small-scale easy to write for a beginner apps that make use of a sql database?

Just to be clear - I **don't** want to make use of a sql server.  I want to write something that at its minimum is an executable file, a database file, and a library file in the same directory. In other words something I can distribute easily.

edit: I'm using Borland C++ builder 2009.

Comment: Just an observation, but how is it that people that "have no clue what I'm doing" end up picking C++ as their language for development? The hardest mainstream language to use.

Comment: I'll gladly answer that.  I went to University 13 years ago and learned C++ via Borland C++ Builder.  I then spent the next 10 years after Uni doing almost no C++ and developing web programming skills (php, asp, css, javascript, jquery and so on)... So the reason I chose C++ is it's the only language I have any experience writing standalone apps in.  And the reason I have no clue is a) the amount of time not doing it and b) the fact that when I did do it I never had to try anthing more complicated than use the stuff built into builder.

Comment: Also... the 'I have no clue what I'm doing' doesn't refer to the ability to code in C++.  It refers to the ability to use the mammoth IDE that is Borland/Codegear C++ Builder

Comment: That makes more sense then. It did seem as though you were referencing your knowledge of C++ not Borland Builder, so my mistake. C++ is a very confusing language, so I was just curious.

Comment: C++ is confusing if you do not know when and when not to use it, and do not appreciate its strengths and weaknesses. But then again under those circumstances any language could be confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try sqlite amalgamation? Basically it's just one source file to include in your project.  If you compile through, you can use it.

See http://www.sqlite.org/download.html.

Comment: I did try that.  I get the linker errors (unresolved external _sqlite_open... and so on)

Comment: I've added the c file to the project using 'add file to project' and now it seems to be working.  I guess I'll accept your answer as the amalgamated file and adding it to the project worked.  I didn't think I'd need to specifically add a file like that.  I would have thought #include "sqlite3.h" would have done that.

Comment: Now that I've got it working I agree.  I was able to write a neat little app with it. It's MUCH more intuitive and user-friendly than the built-in database stuff in c++ builder.